# Electric frequency conversion from very low frequencies

Tags: frequency, electricity, component-selection, power-generation

I have designs for diy home generator that at the scale I’m currently building will output a very small amount of power at a very low frequency, varying between <1 and ~2 hertz using 2 pole magnets.

I’m going to want to convert that into a usable frequency, so a huge jump to 50 or 60hz.

Is there anything affordable out there which will allow me to do that, or are there designs anywhere that someone can share for affordable DIY.

To simplify things for anyone answering, the RPM for my design is fixed at no more than one hundred.

Comment: You will probably need to rectify the 1-2 Hz and then convert the DC to 50-60 Hz.

Comment: You need to increase that frequency by increasing the number of poles or the size of the capacitors needed will be impractical. Increasing the frequency will also increase the amount of power you produce.

Comment: About how big is impractical Kevin? Also, how high would I want to get it, bare minimum how many poles will i be looking to have?

Comment: Yeah, 60 poles would bring it up to 50hz at 100 RPM, thats one option. That’s probably what I’ll end up doing. For cost efficiency at that point, i may want to use square magnets for the stator, do you know by chance  if that will tend to pose a problem down the line?

Comment: The driving power will probably be pretty small, how can I determine what sort of losses i should expect for that conversion if i go low-pole?

Comment: I moved my comment to my answer and responded to questions there.

Answer (score 0):

If the driving power is very small, you will lose it all in power conversion. You may think it is not practical to build a 60 pole generator, but you may find that works where nothing else does.

Here are some 60-pole generators that have been operating for a bit over 100 years. Note the relative length vs. diameter. These are rated about 2 MVA each. All you need is to make a scale model of one of these. I have been thinking of asking if I can get the drawings to do that.

I would not be surprised if these generators are more than 90% efficient. Over the course of their history, they have been converted from 25 Hz to 60 Hz. Some of them may have been rewound more than once. The efficiency of a smaller version would depend a lot on just what the power level is and how well it is designed. How much power can be generated by a given set of magnets will depend a lot on the magnetic flux path, particularly the air gap. What is used for stator and rotor iron will be important, but I don't know how to quantify that.

With a 60-pole motor, I doubt that square magnets will be a huge issue. That make an irregularity in the air gap that will affect the waveform. There again, quantifying will be difficult.

[image]

Comment: Where are those?

Comment: Prairie du Sac, Wisconsin USA https://www.wisconsinhistory.org/Records/Article/CS337

Answer (score 0):

Some newer washing machines use 'flat' brushless DC motors with a large number of poles. This has spawned some interest in using them for wind generators since they can make useable AC at low rotation speeds. In particular, the Fisher and Paykel 'Smart Drive' motors use permanent-magnet rotors, making them easy to use as generators.

Some examples:

https://www.instructables.com/id/A-Vertical-Wind-Generator-from-Washing-Machine-Mot/

https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2766/which-types-of-spare-electric-motors-from-common-consumer-appliances-are-suitabl